# How to declare dependencies of a Gradle custom task?

Tags: gradle, dependencies

If I've created a custom task:

```
class MyTask extends DefaultTask {
   ...
}
```

I can at another time create an instance and declare dependencies:

```
task(["type": MyTask, "dependsOn": importantThing], "MyTaskName")
```

However, it seems a bit weird to separate the task definition from the declaration of dependencies. That is, it seems like everything defining the task should be in one place, or else it would be easy to instantiate the task without the right dependencies. Is there some better way to do this?

Comment: You can configure dependencies in a constructor for instance with `dependsOn`. But strings must be used there, because at the time of task creation other task may not exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tasks should be generic and self-contained. They should only operate on their own input properties, and should not assume existence of other tasks. Declaring tasks and their dependencies is the responsibility of build scripts and/or plugins.

Comment: So there should be no tasks that depend on other tasks? Don't testing tasks in general depend on being able to compile/run code? JaCoCo being meaningless without Java comes to mind. From http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html, "If the Java plugin is also applied to your project, a new task named jacocoTestReport is created that depends on the test task". Do I misunderstand?

Comment: A `Test` task requires class files as its inputs; it doesn't care where they come from. The behavior you cite is provided by the JaCoCo *plugin*.