# How to define gradle tasks dependency in a task in custom gradle plugin

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, gradle-plugin

I'm writing a custom gradle plugin in which I want to have a bunch of common for several of my projects tasks and a sort of a 'main' task to control which of these tasks to turn on.

Regular tasks in the plugin are e.g.:
CopyDockerResourcesTask
CopyContainerFilesTask
PerformAnalysisTask

and the 'main' task is:
**BaseProjectTask**

so then in the project in build.gradle I'd like to be able to do this:

```
BaseProjectTask {
  copyDockerResources = true
  copyContainerFiles = true
  performAnalysis = true
}
```

I want the default behaviour of the plugin to be to not to do anything, only add certain tasks if they are turned on in BaseProjectTask.

I wanted to achieve this with adding task dependency in **@TaskAction** method of BaseProjectTask:

```
class BaseProjectTask extends DefaultTask {

    private final BaseProjectExtension extension
    private final Project project

    @Optional
    @Input
    Boolean copyContainerFiles = false
    ...

    @Inject
    BaseProjectTask(Project project, BaseProjectExtension extension) {
        this.project = project
        this.extension = extension
    }

    @TaskAction
    def execute() {
        if (copyContainerFiles) {
            project.tasks.assemble.dependsOn(project.tasks.copyContainerFiles)
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Creating task dependency, this line:

```
project.tasks.assemble.dependsOn(project.tasks.copyContainerFiles)
```

doesn't work.

Edit:
My current findings are that defining task dependency in @TaskAction is too late as this is execution phase. I could do it in the constructor (this way it works) but its too early as property **copyContainerFiles** isn't set yet.

Does anyone know a way of adding code in the task class that would be fired in the configuration phase? I think this is what I'm missing.

Comment: You need to create an extension, register it, and then use these properties in your task https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:getting_input_from_the_build

Comment: I have an extension, and the properties work, what's not working is this creating task dependency, this line:
```
project.tasks.assemble.dependsOn(project.tasks.copyContainerFiles)
```

Comment: define "not working"

Comment: when I use the plugin and in my build.gradle add
BaseProjectTask {
  copyContainerFiles = true
}
the task 'copyContainerFiles' isn't executed when I run gradle build.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure task dependencies during the build configuration phase, as you surmised.

It's not possible to do it in the `@TaskAction` method. It's fundamental to the way Gradle works that it needs to know how tasks depend on each other before it starts executing the build. That allows Gradle to do some useful things, such as only executing the tasks that are not up to date, or working out what tasks will execute without actually executing them.

In general, tasks should not be aware of one another<sup>1</sup>.

When you are trying to do this in a plugin using values in a project extension, you must wait until after the project has evaluated so that the build script code executes first. You can do this with `project.afterEvaluate()`<sup>2</sup>.

So you can do the following (using Kotlin DSL<sup>3</sup>):

```
project.afterEvaluate {
   tasks.register("baseTask") {
      if (baseProjectExtension.copyDockerResources)
         dependsOn(tasks.getByName("copyDockerResources"))
      if (baseProjectExtension.copyContainerFiles)
         dependsOn(tasks.getByName("copyContainerFiles"))
      if (baseProjectExtension.performAnalysis)
         dependsOn(tasks.getByName("performAnalysis"))
   } 
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>See [How to declare dependencies of a Gradle custom task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24760654/how-to-declare-dependencies-of-a-gradle-custom-task)

<sup>2</sup>See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:project_evaluation

<sup>3</sup>What I am familiar with. Hopefully not too much trouble to convert to Groovy.